# Meaning of 「いらないなら、いいけど 」

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Context:

[image: context]

I am torn between three meanings:

- It's ok if you don't need it (You don't want it)
- If you don't need it, then ok (I'll take it)
- I don't need it, but ok (I'll take it)

Comment: Can be 1 or 2, never 3. Need more context mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "If you don't want this, I don't mind", but the implication depends on the situation.

- If the girl is trying to give this doll to someone (which is likely), the text means "If you don't want this, I don't mind (and I'll keep this with me)".
- If someone is trying to push this doll to this girl (which I don't think is very likely unless she is *tsundere*), the text means "If you don't want this, I don't mind (and I'll receive it)".